# didReceiveLocalNotification method not called in app delegate when app is in background [iOS6]

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, uilocalnotification

I have added a local notification, it is getting triggered as well by displaying a banner on iOS6 and displaying alert in iOS5.

But in iOS6 the **"didReceiveLocalNotification"** method in app delegate is not getting called.

How can I know that a notification has occurred when the application is in the **background**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will never gets called in background. It will be called when your app is in foreground.

Check [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) link for more info

Comment: is there any way that I will know that a notification has happened? I need to know this because I wanted to call a method that will perform somethings. Thanks.

Comment: No, notifications are handled by iOS not your app. If you apps isen't running in the foreground you app will not be notified that the user has received an notification.

Comment: I want to perform some action every time user presses "View" button. On Pressing "View" button the app is opening from my local notification and that is fine but i also want to update my DB when user Presses "View" from Local Notification. Please help me if anyone knows.

Comment: @ManthanPatel you may take a look to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys and UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey there