# UILocalNotifications algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have a problem scheduling `UILocalNotifications`.
My case is this: when user selects motivation category there is a dialog screen where he selects how many times in a day, week, month, motivation message should be presented to him. Then he selects time period: a day, week or a month. A motivation category has messages, and every category has different number of messages.

So my question is: how should i schedule those notifications? Main problem i think is that there can be more than one category. Can someone tell me how to do this?

I know that i cant schedule more than 64 notifications, so i cant schedule all notifications when category is selected. And i know i could reschedule notifications in
 `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
or
`application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

I hope i have been clear about my problem.

Comment: i had same issue as yours and rescheduled all notification (which are saved to db) on same methods. I will follow post if there is better way. If there is no other way available, you can also save notification (time, message, category..) and check them while rescheduling.

Comment: Whats your current set up? What have you tried so far? This is relevant to answerers so we don't complicate things by offer a suggestion not relevant to your goal. It also creates workflow efficiency so we don't try things you've already attempted. It's also important  to show you've put effort into it as well

Answer (score 1):

- First write a function that manages the local notifications
  that is it has to check if there are 64 notifications scheduled if not then you may add some notification.(you have to handle DB part well for example setting the flags correctly)
- Call the function in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` just in case some notifications are expired or missed
- You have to call the function in all the places where local notification is handled.

  1. **The user taps a custom action button in an iOS 8 notification.**

     In this case, iOS calls 
     `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:`

     You also get the *local notification object*, so that you can retrieve any information you need to handle the action.
  2. **The user taps the default button in the alert or taps the app icon.**

     The system launches the app and the app calls its delegate’s  method, passing in the *local notification object*
     `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

  [image]

  3. **The notification is delivered when the app is running in the foreground.**

     The app calls the *UIApplicationDelegate* method 
     `application:didReceiveLocalNotification`:

[Reference1:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4)

[Reference2:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020285/730807)

I hope this helps.

If it doesn't cover your problem feel free to ask doubts

Answer (score 0):

It works as pool when you utilized all your available notifications then you need to reschedule the free notifications in

`application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` but every time you are gonna reschedule you can find next notification to user that could be in today, tomorrow. Whenever you are in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` findout when to notify next and schedule.