# didReceiveLocalNotification Method is not called when application in suspended state

Tags: objective-c, ios9, uilocalnotification

I fired `LocalNotification` 5 minutes from current time. Then I stopped the application and killed it from background. I received local notification after 5 minutes. While taping on the app icon got opened but `didReceiveLocalNotification` Method is not called.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244066/application-didreceivelocalnotification-not-fired-ios7) and [this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244281/applicationdidreceivelocalnotification-never-called-on-ios-8). May this will help you.

Comment: If i received notification ,when application is on background clicking on notification bar app open  below method 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions                       
but if i received notification if i click on the application icon not from the notification bar i am unable to get which method will be fired.

Comment: @sonureshma, for u if u schedule localnotification, how u firing didreceivelocalnotification delegate method in iOS 10, bcas, its not firing in iOS 10. Did u able to handled it?

Answer (score 0):

Please post some code for better answer.
In the meantime test your app on device.Sometime notification methods working on device but not working on simulator.

use this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{

}
```

Comment: testing on device only.

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification is only called when your app is in the FOREGROUND. So when it's in the background and you click the notification banner, it would not call that method. Check out: developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/…